# Laravel4 Entrust - Installation issue with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, migration, constraints, laravel-4

I am installing the laravel 4 package Entrust.
I create the migration file.
When i try to run the migration i get an error regarding the foreign key constraint.
Is this an issue pretty regarding some PhpMyAdmin settings?
I copy under the error directly from powershell:

PS C:\wamp\www\lab\x_pat> php artisan entrust:migration

Tables: roles, assigned_roles, permissions, permission_role
An migration that creates 'roles', 'assigned_roles', 'permissions', 'permission_role' tables will be created in app/data
base/migrations directory

Proceed with the migration creation? [Yes|no]yes

Creating migration...
Migration successfully created!

PS C:\wamp\www\lab\x_pat> php artisan migrate

Migration table created successfully.

[Exception]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `assigned_roles` add const
  raint assigned_roles_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`)) (Bindings: array (
  ))

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

In PhpMyAdmin in had just to go in the table that contains the foreign key and press on INDEX button. In this way an index is created on that foreign key and then in RELATION VIEW is possible to assign the foreign key to the proper id of the proper table.

I think was just that the solution.

Comment: Looks like whoever prepared the migration SQL file forgot about this index. Did this file come from the application itself?

Comment: Yet in the migration the indexes was missing, but even adding them was giving the same error. I had to add them manually.

Comment: Sorry Marc, can i make you the last question: when assigning the foreign key, it is correct to leave ON DELETE - RESTRICT and ON-UPDATE - RESTRICT?

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key constraints are not enforced by phpMyAdmin (which is a web interface) but by the MySQL server.

There are many possibilities for this error; it might be because the tables' structure do not permit it (missing indexes for example), or because of the existing data itself that does not respect the constraint you want to add.

Comment: Thank you Marc. Yes it was the missing indexes.
I do not undestand what they are, yet in this way i managed to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the missing reference on adding the foreign key (user_id) references users (id). Please ensure that the user table is exist prior to running the entrust migration.

Answer (score 1):

I had to ensure my users table had its 'id' column attribute set to 'unsigned'. This matches the user_id column attribute in the entrust assigned_roles table. That allowed the migration to proceed for me.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is in the file EntrustSetupTables in the migration folder, in this lines :

```
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Just put the name of the table users after the .on() and the problem will be solved.